# DocBook XML, Between File Link Structure? TOC?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, docbook

I've converted a bunch of old school presentation files to Docbook XML, and each file appears as expected.  I intend to convert them to XHTML/HTML , and my test conversions look great.  My only question is how to create a proper directory structure with links, I'm just not sure what process to consider.  For example ... I'm looking to have links, to other converted Docbook pages, on the footers of the pages.  If anyone has an idea to consider, I would appreciate the input.

Additionally with regards to XSLT, I'm using xsltproc which only supports XSLT 1.0 + common EXSLT modules. xsltproc is the command-line interface of libxslt, which still does not support XSLT 2.0.  Regardless even though specific examples are great, I really need to know the general approach.  With that information I could search further, to eventually locate specific examples.

Comment: Do you use [DocBook-XSL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/files/docbook-xsl/) or some other stylesheets?

Comment: I do use DocBook-XSL, to convert the DocBooks to XHTML.  I may customize it eventually, or possibly create another XSL to process after conversion.

Comment: @TechZilla, You need to establish a convention about the naming of the different HTML files and about the directory structure. The link from filename1.html to filename2.html can be as simple as: `<a href="filename2.html">filename2</a>` -- if all files are in the same directory.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I appreciate your input, as I know your a true XSLT expert. ...anyway... All my Docbook XML files are named in a fairly solid convention.  For example, they are named like this `/1/file.xml`, and those values correlate to these XML lines, `<refentrytitle>FILE</refentrytitle>
<volnum>1</volnum>`

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: So they're not exactly in the same directory, and the title is often in wrong case, but it's consistent across all the Docbook XML files.  Example Docbook XML fragment, which would be linking to another page, `<citerefentry><refentrytitle>FILE2</refentrytitle><volnum>1</volnum></citerefentry>`.

Comment: @TechZilla, And does your EXSLT implementation support the `<exsl:document>` extension element? If so, the solution is rather easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given this source XML document**:

```
<ref>
    <refentrytitle>FILE</refentrytitle>
    <volnum>1</volnum>
</ref>
```

**then the this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vU" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vL" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:template match="ref">
   <a href="/{volnum}/{translate(refentrytitle, $vU, $vL)}.xml">
     <xsl:value-of select="refentrytitle"/>
   </a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<a href="/1/file.xml">FILE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well with XSLT 2.0 as supported by processors like Saxon 9, XmlPrime or AltovaXML you can create several result documents with one stylesheet, using `xsl:result-document` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees. Usually you use modes http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes to process input nodes twice or even more times, with one mode you create the individual pages, with a second mode the toc.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using XSLT 1.0, with the possibility of libxslt implemented EXSLT.  Additionly creating many pages is not a problem, as I have already created many properaly named pages. I'm trying to understand how they all can link together.  The purpose is to create XHTML pages, with footer links to other XHTML converted pages.

Comment: If somehow the TOC can provide my specified features, please elaborate in how this is approached.